# How to find the remainder value for this calculation in JavaScript or Java?

Tags: javascript, java

Why this calculation remainder is not giving me 0.0 as the result?

I tried in Java and Javascript and the result is always the same:

```
double number = 270.48;
double divisor = 90.16;

System.out.println( (number % divisor) );
```

The result is always **2.8421709430404007E-14** but it should be **0.0**

Comment: Same reason that 1 / 3 won't give you a number that is exactly equals to a third of the unit. Computers are not capable to represent the mathematical continuous "real" numbers, and instead provide approximations of calculations on them. The number you obtained is very small, a rather good approximation to zero. That's what you get on computers when trying to use decimal numbers in place of whole numbers.

Comment: Probably shouldn't ask for an answer in two completely different languages.  I recommend sticking to one, especially because this is not Javascript code.  At least post both if you want information on both.

Comment: Floating points.

Comment: BigDecimal class in java